# How to load page on success login or display error message ?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I'm trying to build a web site as follow:
- There is a login page, where I'm using post command to send the user name and password to the server.
- If the details are OK, the server send other web page to be loaded,
- Else an error message will be displayed.

Client side (html & JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#loginButton").click(function()
                {       
                    var username = $("input#username").val();
                    var password = $("#password").val();                    
                    $.post( "/login", { userName: username, pass: password })
                      .done(function( data ) {
                         $("#loginResult").text(data);
                      });
                });
            });
```

Server side (NodeJs):

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

    var userName = req.body.userName;
    var pass = req.body.pass;

    if(req.body.userName && req.body.pass) 
    {
        db.collection("customers").findOne({first_name:userName}, function(err, doc) 
        {
          if(doc) {
            res.sendFile('userPage.html', {root: __dirname })
          }
          else {
            res.send('ERR')
          }
        });
    }  
    else
    {       
        res.send('ERR') 
    }

});
```

If the details are wrong, I can see the error message,
But, if the details are OK, the new page (userPage.html) is not loaded.
1. Why ? 
2. Is this the right way to do login process ?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you have a file called 'userPage.html' at the root directory of your app and your mongo operation is successful which you make it sound like it is it will return the contents of it to your ajax call and the markup of it should be inserted as text in the element. Try to do some debugging see how far the code gets and let us know if the server throws any errors if you need further help with that.

However, this is absolutely not how you should do authentication. First you should avoid setting up a login and registration algorithm on your own. There are too many things to consider. And some of them you've already gotten wrong like - you're storing passwords as plain text, which is a big no. I'd use "passportjs" there are many nice tutorials online. Like this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local where you can learn how to use it in your app real quick,

As for the front-end if you are going to do an asynchronous call - meaning not go to a different page you shouldn't really send back a page but rather an acknowledgement. If you want to redirect to a page after login just have a form with a post action like in the above tutorial.